# f.el: f-split behaviour

Tags: files, path, libraries

Using `f-split` from [f.el](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el):

```
(require 'f)
(f-split "c:/a/b")
```

returns

```
("/" "c:" "a" "b")
```

What is the rationale? Shouldn't it be  `("c:" "a" "b")`?

Also in Emacs for Windows the value of:

```
(f-path-separator)
```

is `"/"`. When is this value supposed to be different, if not in Windows?

Comment: See also https://github.com/rejeep/f.el/issues/80.

Comment: Is your question about the _order_ of the list elements? Just what are you asking, in your last question about MS Windows? Are you asking about slash versus backslash or something else. The question is not very clear.

Comment: @Drew: I expect `"c:/a/b"` components to be `("c:" "a" "b")`. Under Windows the separator should be `"\\"`.

Comment: 1. I think you need to ask the maintainer of `fsplit.el` whether this is by design (and why). 2. Emacs uses slash, not backslash, everywhere for file names, including for MS Windows. You can input file names with backslashes but (a) you need not and (b) they are converted to slashes anyway.

Comment: @Drew: There may be situations where you need to run an external Windows command using a path argument. In these cases "\\" may be better than "/" (while Windows can often cope with both). This would make a platform dependant `f-path-separator` useful. Apart from that, if under Windows/Linux/MacOS is always "/", what is the use case of `f-path-separator`? This is what I meant with my second question.

Comment: 1. Yes, there are cases where you might want backslashes, for use outside Emacs. 2. I know nothing about `f-path-separator` or `f-split.el`. If you don't get the answer you want here, consider asking the library's maintainer.